# How to implement RAM bundle and Inline Requires react native

Tags: react-native

I am using react native to build project and I am facing a problem with long launch time, I try to follow https://reactnative.dev/docs/ram-bundles-inline-requires, however it is not so clear about Investigating the Loaded Modules, and how to put only the necessary modules for first screen.
I am not also able to find index.(ios|android).js file (is it index.android.bundle).
If you can tell me how to extract only necessary modules and recommend docs or examples about implementing that?

Comment: How complex is your app? Are you sure your launch times are due to bundle size?

Comment: it is not complex, only articles with text and images,the launch time is 4 seconds if i put json data inside app and 12 seconds if fetch from url.

Comment: I don't believe your issue will be solved by inline requires or RAM bundles. If you are able to share the code for your app then there may be other suggestions for improving speed.

Comment: Are you using [hermes](https://engineering.fb.com/2019/07/12/android/hermes/) engine?

Answer (score 2):

With considering the [official documents](https://reactnative.dev/docs/ram-bundles-inline-requires#inline-requires), pay attention to this example:

You have a `Main screen` (view) in your app like `HomeScreen`

In your HomeScreen, there are more and more components and logic in this page but assume we have a `SettingsModal`.

usually, `modals` will open when you touch a button.

**Without inline require**

you have to import your modal component to your HomeScreen at the top level of your module

**with inline require**

you will import your modal component to your HomeScreen when it needs to show!

Let's do this with code:

**HomeScreen without inline require**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {View, Text, Pressable} from 'react-native'
import SettingsModal from 'components/modal'

function HomeScreen() {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

    const handleShowModal = () => setShowModal(prevState => !prevState)
   
    return (
       <View>
          <Text> Home Screen </Text>

          <Pressable onPress={handleShowModal}>
              <Text> show settings </Text>             
          </Pressable >

          {
            showModal 
                ?  <SettingsModal />
                :  null
          }
       </View>
    )
}
```

In the above example, we import **`SettingsModal`** in our HomeScreen top level with React and View and Text...

**HomeScreen with inline require**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {View, Text, Pressable} from 'react-native'

let SettingsModal = null;

function HomeScreen() {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

    const handleShowModal = prevState => {
         if (SettingsModal == null) {
             SettingsModal = require('components/modal').SettingsModal
         }
         
         setShowModal(prevState => !prevState)
    }
   
    return (
       <View>
          <Text> Home Screen </Text>

          <Pressable onPress={handleShowModal}>
              <Text> show settings </Text>             
          </Pressable >

          {
            showModal 
                ?  <SettingsModal />
                :  null
          }
       </View>
    )
}
```

In the above example, we check if `SettingsModal` has not been imported yet, then we will import this component to our HomeScreen file (after user touch the show settings button)

Comment: This example is same as the code snippet in official doc